# how to input data array looping to database

Tags: php, mysql

i have a code like this, i dont know what wrong with my code

```
$peringkat=0;
//pencarian ranking terbesar ke terkecil berdasarkan value
$ranking = array("$ATTT[0]" => "$HA[0]", "$ATTT[1]" => "$HA[1]");
arsort($ranking);
foreach ($ranking as $alternatif => $nilaialternatif) {
$peringkat++;
echo "
<th class='akhir'><input class='rankingakhir' type='text' name='alternatif' 
value='$alternatif' size='12' readonly></th>
<td class='akhir'><input class='nilaiakhir' type='text' 
name='nilaialternatif' value=".number_format($nilaialternatif, 3, '.', ',')." size='12' readonly></td>
<td class='akhir'><input class='rankakhir' type='text' 
name='rankingalternatif' value='$peringkat' size='12' readonly></td></tr>";
}   
echo '</table><div class="akhir"><input class="akhir" type="submit" 
value="Simpan Ranking ke Database"></div></div></div>
```

i run var dump but just record data from alternatif 2

```
array(3) { ["alternatif"]=> string(12) "Alternatif 2" ["nilaialternatif"]=> string(5) "0.223" ["rankingalternatif"]=> string(1) "2" }
```

table in live design
[image]

my database code

```
$Host = "localhost";         //Memilih host, Localhost berarti komputer itu sendiri
$User = "root";             //Memilih user/pengguna
$Password = "";             //Password, Biasanya Kosong
$db       = "spkjazuly";         //Memilih Database
$konek=mysql_connect($Host,$User,$Password)or die (mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db ($db,$konek) or die (mysql_error("TIdak Terhubung Ke Server 
Mysql")); //Menghubungkan ke Mysql dan memilih Database
mysql_query("replace INTO ranking VALUE(DEFAULT,'$_GET[B11]','$_GET[alternatif]','$_GET[nilaialternatif]','$_GET[rankingalternatif]')") //Perintah Mysql untuk mengisi tabel Tamu
or die(mysql_error("Tidak Berhasil Menyimpan !"));  //Or Die (mysql_error()) Pesan Error
echo "<h1>Berhasil Menyimpan Data</h1>";
```

sory for my english, i try my best.

Comment: I think your question is asking why you are not receiving 2 rows in the resultset, but you have not shown your `SELECT` query.  We cannot help you without more information.

Answer (score -1):

to connect to your DB try this and dont uppercase variables

```
// Connection to DB
    $konek = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;$db', $User, $Password);
    if ($db){
        echo('Connected to: "'.$db.'"');
    }
```